# Cut just one character out of a javascript string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove what is inside the last bracket of a string.

This is the ids string:

```
rule_Group[0][5]
```

This is my Javascript code

```
var str = 'rule_Group[0][5]';

var a = str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
var b = str.lastIndexOf("]") - 1;
var res = str.substr(a,b)

document.write(res)
```

I want to keep the 5 in the brackets. No matter what JS doesn't allow me to cut out just one character. I have even manually tried to do this with no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) has a good JavaScript reference. If a function doesn't seem to be doing what you want you can read about it there. [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) doesn't work the way you've assumed.

Comment: Nice article but what if str = "rule_group[5]"? A well formed re would fail.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Something like `/\[([^\]]+)\]$/` will work. Why do you think it would fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `substring` instead of `substr`.

```
var str = 'rule_Group[0][5]';

var a = str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
var b = str.lastIndexOf("]");
var res = str.substring(a,b)

document.write(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is the length of the substring to return, not an index. So if you know you want just one character, this would work:

```
var a = str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
var res = str.substr(a, 1);
```

Of if you don't know how long the substring is, use this:

```
var a = str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
var b = str.lastIndexOf("]");
var res = str.substr(a, b - a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
var str = 'rule_Group[0][5]';
var numb = str.split('[').pop().replace(']','');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2pCc/1/)

Just seems easier ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this:

```
var a = str.lastIndexOf("[")+1;
var res = str.charAt(a);
```

Try it out and let me know if it works :-)

Cheers,

Roiw

EDIT:

You can use regular expressions if you want (this will work for your case):

```
var str = "rule_Group[0][123456789]";
var patt1=new RegExp("^.*?\\[.*?\\[");  
var patt2=new RegExp("\\].*?$");
var result = str.replace(patt1,"");
result = result.replace(patt2,"");
```

Cheers,

Roiw

Comment: Using regular expressions solve for that case, and even more complex cases.